# PyQt5 QImage isn't reading the image from 2D grayscale array correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qimage

My code down gave me odd results, as seen in the attached photo **QImage to the left**, and **ndarray to the right**.

How can I solve the problem of transforming 2D grayscale ndarray to QImage correctly please?

- [image: QImage]

  - **Edit**: The Original Image is here:
- [image: Original]

```
qimage = QImage(Image, Image.shape[0],Image.shape[1],QImage.Format_Mono).scaled(308, 384, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation) 
print(Image.shape)
plt.imshow(Image,cmap=plt.cm.bone)
plt.show()
self.image = QPixmap(qimage)
self.LB_Image_Orig.setPixmap(self.image)
self.LB_Image_Orig.adjustSize()
QApplication.processEvents()
```

Comment: share the image please

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358003/show-matplotlib-imshow-output-in-qt/60358264#60358264

Comment: @eyllanesc I uploaded the image to the question due to your request.

Comment: If your image is a .png then use  `pixmap = QPixmap("/path/of/image")`

Comment: @eyllanesc no, it's in dicom format, and I'm manipulating it before to show, the solution to save the image in png and load it later worked, thanks that worked indeed, but I was asking if there is a way to show it directly without saving to harddisk .

Comment: Okay, so I will be more precise: Provide the input (in your case the dicom image) and the necessary code, that is, you must provide an [MRE]

Comment: @eyllanesc dicom images are subject to privacy constraints, they contain patients information, and the idea you propsed worked well thanks so much  ``` imsave('image.png', Image.astype(np.float))
            self.image = QPixmap('image.png')
            self.LB_Image_Orig.setPixmap(self.image)
            self.LB_Image_Orig.adjustSize()
            if os.path.exists("image.png"):
                os.remove("image.png") ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **eyllanesc** for his proposed solution which was to write the image as PNG and read it directly from disk:

```
from skimage.io import imsave, imread

imsave('image.png', Image.astype(np.float))
self.image = QPixmap('image.png')
self.LB_Image_Orig.setPixmap(self.image)
self.LB_Image_Orig.adjustSize()
QApplication.processEvents()

if os.path.exists("image.png"):
 os.remove("image.png")
```

Comment: This seems wrong to me. Firstly, you appear to be trying to save `float` values in a PNG, but PNG format doesn't support `float`. Secondly, you appear to be writing to disk unnecessarily. Unfortunately, there isn't enough information in your question or answer to really know what your starting point is at is unclear where your variable `Image` came from or what type/dimension it is.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I agree with you that the concept is not correct, but practically it worked with me, Image you can consider it the ,PNG file above, same data and same dimensions, since I can't share the Dicom image.

Comment: Have you tried `qpixmap=QPixmap(QImage(img.data, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], QImage.Format_RGB888))`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried that with all kinds of Format_xxxx no one of them worked.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant when I said there isn't enough information in your question because I cannot deduce the type and shape of your `Image` variable - you don't show where it came from.

Comment: So are you going to say how you went from a PNG file to your variable `Image`?

Comment: @mark-setchell `from scipy.io imoprt imread`  then `Image= imread('image.png')`

Comment: No `imread` in `scipy.io` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/io.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry it's [skimage](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread)

Answer (score 0):

use Grayscale8 format:

`qimage = QImage(Image, Image.shape[0],Image.shape[1],QImage.Format_Grayscale8).scaled(308, 384, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)`